# How do I make a group of multi-select checkboxes in ASP.Net MVC with c# enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I need to make a set of checkboxes where a user can select 1 or more markets. I would normally use a set of boolean values to accomplish this as it would be pretty strait forward and in my mind not take up much space in the database or take that long to load as they are only boolean values. It was suggested to me that I could use a single enum value in the database for the list of checkboxes. For example here is the enum

```
[Flags]
public enum Markets 
{

    Canada = 2,
    USA = 4,
    Iceland = 8,
    Brazil = 16,
    Italy = 32,
    Japan= 64,

}
```

Then in the database I could store 14 for Canada Usa and Iceland.
I was wondering is enums the way to go in MVC for checkboxes and if so how would it work?

Note i'm using C# MVC4 and entity framework 5 but i'm about to transition to MVC5 entity framework 6.

Comment: So, if I need to find all records with (at least) Brazil and Japan checked, I'll need to do something like `SELECT * FROM SomeTable T WHERE T.Markets & 16 = 16 AND T.Markets & 64 = 64`. This is not only ugly as hell, it is also inefficient (you cannot index the `Markets` column). Unless you are working with a really constrained environment, I would not follow that path.

Comment: Would you suggest using a bool for each checkbox instead because that is what I normally do

Comment: Certainly. Also, if you are using SQL Server, remember that the `BIT` dataype is optimized. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx: "If there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, the columns are stored as 1 byte. If there are from 9 up to 16 bit columns, the columns are stored as 2 bytes, and so on.". And, of course, you could also follow the complete normalization path (create a `Markets` table, and add another table for the n * n relationship).

Comment: @rsenna yes, actually I am using sql server so this is good news. Makes things much more clear and I am very happy to see that it is the efficient way to go as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward in ASP.NET MVC, just make sure you have a list of inputs on your page with the same name and that you are binding to a list on the backend.

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/UpdateInts">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Markets" value="Canada" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Markets" value="USA" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Markets" value="Iceland" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Markets" value="Brazil" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

That should do it. You could use the HtmlHelpers to create them or just use Razor Syntax.

Here is some more helpful info.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: I would iterate over the list of enums to create the inputs, so when one is added the MVC code does not need to change.

Comment: Idk if i'm just missing it but i'm trying to take a single enum value from the database and decide which checkboxes should be selected from there.

Comment: to make an input checkbox checked, you need to have an attribute of "checked" on the input tag. With ASP.NET MVC helpers this value is a boolean. Otherwise in your loop just do a boolean check.